# Can I interact with fiddler using C++

Tags: fiddler

Does Fiddler4 have any API, or any type of scripting language I could then execute on fiddler?

I'm thinking about using basic features such as a breakpoint on a certain file(That I can do on the QuickExec console normally) and automate that. Or something that resembles to fiddlercore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Teleric offers [FiddlerCore](https://www.telerik.com/fiddlercore) the Proxy part of Fiddler as C# library. Not sure how to integrate something like that in a C++ application. Additionally it is commercial and the price is not cheap.

Comment: I wrote a [guide](https://mika-s.github.io/fiddler/extension/2019/04/09/creating-a-fiddler-extension-1.html) for creating extensions in Fiddler using C#. Maybe it can help you. If C# works then perhaps C++/CLI works.